# Add an elseif statement for wordpress page using woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

I've tried several different things, but with no good results.  I'm attempting to add an elseif which will allow me to echo "Enquire for Price" instead of a price if left blank on a wordpress.org site that uses Woocommerce.  Instead, the price is being shown as 0 or EnquireforPrice£0.  Our custom theme doesn't have a price.html or loop.html file, so I can't edit those.  The price.html file in single-product (woocommerce folder) shows EnquireforPrice£(whatever the original price was) when I tried to edit it with the elseif I found on [this wordpress woocommerce support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-woocommerce-excelling-ecommerce-changing-out-of-stock-to-coming-soon)

This is my current code that doesn't allow for enquire for price and for some reason I'm drawing a blank on how to get it to work.

```
<?php echo ($product->get_stock_quantity() < 1) ? '<span class="sold">Sold</span>' : null; ?><?php if ($product->get_stock_quantity() != 0) : ?><p class="price"><?php echo woocommerce_price(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_price', true)); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
```

Basically, I need it to say Enquire for price if the price is left blank in the individual product price, but if there is a price to list the price.  It should be straight forward, yet for some reason it simply isn't.

Thanks for any help that can be offered!

PS  I've also tried the wordpress plugins that are supposed to do this, but they only work on the product page and leave £0 on the home and search pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded woocommerce and have it working for me. Open

```
plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/price.php
```

Find this line

```
<p itemprop="price" class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
```

Replace it with the code below

```
<p itemprop="price" class="price">
    <?php 
        $price = $product->get_price_html();
        if(empty($price))
        {
            echo '<a href="link">Anchor Text</a>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo $price;
        }; 
    ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Sadly, it isn't showing the prices that should be there...instead it changes it to the text that should be showing only if the price is left blank.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, it always shows anchor text regardless. So no prices are showing anymore, just the anchor text.

Comment: Ahhh...I need it to show the price and if there is no price set in woocommerce for it to show the anchor text.  Thanks for the try!

Comment: @user2945487 I have updated my answer. I actually downloaded woocommerce and tested the above and it is working for me on a single product page

Comment: @user2945487 Also remember if you go with this solution and update the plugin, you will have to put this code back in.